# Python - Flatten lists of lists of two different types in one function

Tags: python

As input, I receive two types of lists of lists made of x and y coordinates that represent polygon and multipolygon geometries. In fact the input is represented in the [GeoJson standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON)

`list1` represents coordinates of a simple polygon geometry and `list2` represent a multipolygon geometry:

```
list1 = [[[0 , 0], [0, 1], [0 ,2]]]

list2 = [[[[0, 0] , [0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1 ,2]]]]
```

Multipolygon geometry (`list2`) are represented by a list of lists one level deeper than simple polygon geometry (`list1`).

I want to flatten those lists in order to get those output:

```
   if input is list1 type : list1_out = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2]]

   if input is list2 type : list2_out = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]]
```

I am using the following code that is usually used to flatten lists where `input` can be a list of the two types:

```
[coords for polygon in input for coords in polygon]
```

With this code above, the output for `list1` is correct but the output of `list2` is the following:

```
[[[0, 0] ,[0, 1], [0, 2]], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]]
```

Is there a function that could deeply flatten those two types of lists to get the expected output?

**Edit: Performance really matter here as the lists are really big**

**Edit 2: I can use a if sentence to filter each type of list**

Comment: So, you want to flatten the inner-most lists only? Also, does it need to auto-detect what kind of list it is?

Comment: Yes that's a good summary!

Comment: Shouldn't the result for the `list2` rather be `[[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]]]`? (One more level of `[]`)

Comment: No, the output for `list2` must be the same structure as `list1`, ie, a list of every polygon's coordinates present in the feature

Comment: Any reason why the lists are double nested? It seems that your data could adequately be represented by a list of lists (`[[0, 1], [2, 3], ...]`) without the additional nesting.

Comment: @JoelCornett You are right, but the data is represented in the geojson standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON

Comment: @tobias_k no need to auto-detect, I can filter by the geometry type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

for `list1`

```
[sum(x, []) for x in list1]
```

for `list2`

```
[sum(x, []) for a in list2 for x in a]
```

**Demo**

```
>>> list1 = [[[0 , 0], [0, 1], [0 ,2]]]
>>> list2 = [[[[0, 0] , [0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1 ,2]]]]
>>> [sum(x, []) for x in list1]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2]]
>>> [sum(x, []) for a in list2 for x in a]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting your data to `numpy.array`, you can use `reshape`:

```
import numpy as np
t = np.array([[[[0, 0] , [0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1 ,2]]]])
print t.shape  # (1, 2, 3, 2) 
t = np.reshape([1, 2, 6])  # merging the last 2 coordinates/axes
```

flattens the second list as you want.

A code which works for both list (since in both cases you want to merge the last to axis) is:

```
t = np.array(yourList)
newShape = t.shape[:-2] + (t.shape[-2] * t.shape[-1], )  # this assumes your 
# arrays are always at least 2 dimensional (no need to flatten them otherwise...)
t = t.reshape(t, newShape)
```

The key thing is to keep the shape unchanged up to the last 2 axes (hence 
`t.shape[:-2]`), but to merge the two last axes together (using an axis of length `t.shape[-2] * t.shape[-1]`)

We are creating the new shape by concatenation of these two tuples (hence the extra comma after the multiplication).

Edit: `np.reshape()` doc is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). The important parameters are the input array (your list, cast as an array), and a tuple which I've called `newShape`, which represents the lengths along the new axes.

Comment: can you explain how to use reshape(), especially the meaning of the parameters in this case?

Comment: I got this error: `<TypeError>: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'`

Comment: Ok, but now I got: `<TypeError>: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: Yes with the same input, maybe my numpy is not up-to-date

Comment: I got no error, but I am looking in a way to put the result in a string

Comment: What are the specs of this string? `str(t)` ? Your may want to replace EOL by commas

Comment: str(t) returns something like this with real values: `"[[-8170770  5745738 -8170772 ...,  5745736 -8170770  5745738]]"` It's weird... no commas and ... or sometimes \n in the middle.

Comment: Agreed, but then again this is another question, so maybe you should create a new one.